# Attendence Pivot Table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table

I am doing Attendence in PHP and MYSQL. I want to show students Attendence like this format:

| Student Name | Physics | Math | Science |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Riley | Absent | Late | Present |
| Dan | Absent |  | Late |

I want the subjects to be the subjects that the class takes and if the student has no Attendence on this subject I want the status to be null.

My Database is like this:

```
attendence: id, std_id, class_id, attendence_date.     
class:      id, name.    
subjects:   id, name.   
class_subjects: id, class_id, subject_id.    
students:   id, name,class_id.
```

So how can I do pivot Table.

```
BEGIN
SET @sql=null;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(CASE WHEN su.subject_name = ''',
      su.subject_name,
      ''' THEN subject_name ELSE NULL END) AS ',
      su.subject_name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM class_subject cs JOIN subjects su on cs.subject_id=su.id WHERE cs.class_id = p_class;
SET @sql=concat('SELECT s.name, a.state ,',@sql, ' from attendence a join students s on a.std_id=s.id where a.attendence_date = ',p_date);
#SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Comment: Pivoting in SQL is a notorious pain in the xxs neck. You may be better off building your pivoted display with php code.

Comment: how to pivot in php

Comment: Pivot in MySQL:  https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Comment: PHP:  2-D array then flip indexes.  Programming 101.